# Which Databases Should NOT be mirrored in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, mirroring

I'm in the process of creating a mirror for our newly built SharePoint 2013 farm.  I know that the content databases can be mirrored, but what of the other ones?  I know that there were special databases on SP 2010 that you weren't supposed mirror, but I've not been able to find much on Google searches.

I have the following:

- SharePoint_AdminContent databases
- 4 x Search_Service_Application databases
- SharePoint_Farm_Config
- UsageApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in SharePoint 2010 there are two databases that do not support mirroring :

- User Profile Service: Synchronization database
- Web Analytics Service: Staging database

For more details check [Mirroring Support for SharePoint 2010 Databases](http://bidn.com/Blogs/Mirroring-Support-for-SharePoint-2010-Databases)

In SharePoint, 2013 You can mirror all databases, but it's suggested to don't mirror session state database because its data is temporary

Comment: this one for sharepoint 2010, he is asking for 2013. :(

Comment: Thanks @WaqasSarwarMCSE for your hint , I always learn from your hints , but I mentioned "You can mirror all databases, but it's suggested to don't mirror session state database for 2013" , But For 2010 I found this article that may help :) ,

Comment: brother, if you check the article i refer, that will tell all the DBs are supported even session state. that is for 2013. But thank for pointing.  Why raise it, because in a question he said, i know there are some special dbs in 2010 which are not supported....

Comment: Now I think the answer is clear ,

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I don't see your answer , because I was typing my answer , and when I post answer I see your answer , if I know you answered this , I never answer it , and you know that , I only see 2010 at his questions so i preferred to add more details that why i mentioned 2010 but I think my answer was need to be obvious, so thanks for your hint

Comment: brother it does not matter, who answered this...i just want to tell you we should be clear on the answer, Even you respond the same way i did ...i have no issue...end goal is make user happy. it is all volunteer work and sharing is noble thing. So enjoy it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46139/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).

Answer (score 1):

I am sure, mirroring is supported for the all type of databases. But you have to follow the recommendation for that.
check this technet to learn about each Db's supportbility.

[Supported high availability and disaster recovery options for SharePoint databases (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj841106.aspx#SAppDBsSPALL)